# DISM unable to capture a dir located on network disk

Tags: networking, nas, dism, capture

I am trying to capture an image with `DISM`, where the `/capturedir` path is located on a NAS mapped to `Z:` via `net use` in the same elevated command prompt that is running `DISM` (`Z:` works fine with any other utility from the same command prompt, including 7-zip console commands), and I receive error:

```powershell
Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"jobs.wim" /CaptureDir:"z:\sav\jobs" /Name:"test"

  Error: 161
  The specified path is invalid.
```

- I have searched for similar cases, but found nothing, with the closest case being the opposite (`/capturedir` on local disk to NAS)
- At this point, I wonder if it's even possible for `DISM` to capture from NAS

Of course, I can copy the dir to local disk and capture from there, but it's a waste of time, and why can 7-zip capture from NAS where `DISM` can't?

UPDATE 05/12/2021: I'm adding an image showing the problem, as you can see the admin cmd prompt has no problem listing files on both source and destination folder paths,yet DISM from the very same cmd prompt fails saying the path is invalid. I found a similar case [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7bc80696-6c82-4be9-a92a-cac567267e0b/dism-image-capture-to-network)

[image]

Comment: @JW0914 I have used full share hostname address and I get the same error. I suspect that DISM is unable to capture an image from a network drive. Can you do a quick test on your NAS if you have one? Thanks

Comment: @JW0914 really no way for me to get this to work. As I said I have other ways to capture the image but I really don't understand why DISM doesn't capture directly fom the NAS. Please see also my edited content in OP. Maybe DISM runs in a user context with no access privilege to the NAS? NAS has uid+pwd that I validate with net use command before running DISM

Comment: @JW0914 Now I'm creating an image with DISM using the NAS as target and it's progressing regularly, so it seems the problem shows only when the NAS is the source, not when it is destination. Furthermore when choosing NAS destination  the access is in write mode while in NAS source is read only. Seems really like a DISM bug to me

Comment: I apologize as I transposed the capture and save locations, which is why I got a successful capture _(I always list `/CaptureDir` before `/ImageFile`, so when I referenced your command, I didn't catch the transposition until I went back through my terminal history)_. I'll need to do some research over the weekend to figure out why this is, as `Dism` should be able to capture from a network share for deployment from WinPE/WinRE, and am unsure why it's erroring with `0x800700a1` and `161`.

Comment: While I haven't found a solution yet, the issue is an access denied error: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/8C4YyHP)

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks. Now we are in the same situation. I get also the same logs as yours. One possible reason could be that the component generating the error is running under another user ad has no read access to NAS. On the other hand when DISM writes to NAS it has no problems, but that could be a completely different component as these apps are not monolithic but rather granular. Surely someone in DISM team could tell us why, but how to reach them?

Comment: Even though `Dism` is well-documented, I've been unable to find a reason for this, but if  `Dism` doesn't support capturing a network share, I suspect it wasn't built in since its main purpose is to image the OS _(the access denied error is odd since the Admin terminal is still using the user's credentials and can list files in the share)_. I would recommend asking this on the [Spiceworks forum](https://community.spiceworks.com/windows/groups), as Microsoft has vendor reps that monitor the site M-F, with many of the forum members being folks in the IT industry.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the research and suggestions. I will eventually post in the spicework forum or the Microsoft forum itself. It's not urgent since I have 2 workarounds: copy from NAS to local and DISM from local or use 7-ZIP instead of DISM that captures directly from NAS (but with different compression and speed)
It's more the curiosity to understand why? Either DISM has separate net access privileges from CMD prompt or maybe DISM needs NTFS/FAT low level access to get file data and that's not available on NAS. If I discover more I'll update this thread.

Comment: You'll likely want to use Spiceworks over Microsoft's forum for technical issues - Microsoft's forum is for run-of-the-mill basic questions and little help will be found there. Spiceworks has Microsoft support employees [vendor reps] that monitor Spiceworks M - F, responding regularly to posts, combined with the user-base largely being in the IT field _(vendor reps are easily identifiable via what's next to their user name, as are verified IT professionals)_